# Spacing Images Inside of A Wrap Widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am new to Flutter.

I have a row with three columns.

The following image shows what I am referring to:
[Current GUI][1]

I would like to fix the computer's hand, so that the tiles are not only larger, but can be spaced out with the same distance as the human's hand.

The spacing property inside the wrap widget is not accurately changing the spacing between each domino tile widget in the computer's hand. This can be seen in the image I have attached to this post.

The following is the source code I have for the computer's hand:

````
Column(children: [
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 15),
                child: const Text("Computer's Hand:",
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            Wrap(direction: Axis.vertical, spacing: 0.1, children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[0].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[2].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[3].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[3].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[4].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
              Image.asset('assets/${computersHand[5].getTileFace()}.png',
                  height: 111, width: 60),
            ])
          ]),```

Please help me understand how I can accomplish this.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq7Q5.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You want to set 3 things on your screen by horizontally,

First is computer hand column

Second is your column of six container

Third is human hand column

Is it right?

To achieve that set your code structure like

```
Row(
children:[
    
    //Column - code for display your computer hand

    Expanded(
            child: //your column with six containers
    ),

    //Column - code for display your human hand
            
   ]
)
```

Don’t use ‘Material(‘ everywhere in your children widgets because it is already defined in your main class

Comment: Hi. For the seconds column I want the six containers for my fix stacks on the bottom, and another six containers for the computer's six stacks on the top.

Comment: Instead of using Expanded() could I simply make it another column?

Comment: Can you share some sketch of your final output design so I can understand more clearly

Comment: Yes. What I want to accomplish is more clear with the updated image I have attached to this post. I was able to add a row with three columns, but I am finding it difficult to change the spacing for the domino tiles in the computer's hand.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq7Q5.png Here is the image of what I currently have.